# RedShift: Delete statement does not allow table alias?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Got the the following code to try to blow away duplicate entries in the table:

```
DELETE FROM events a
WHERE a.ctid <> (SELECT min(b.ctid)
             FROM   events b
             WHERE  a.eventid = b.eventid and
                    left(b.eventtimestamp,10)='2016-01-15');
```

Tried this with my query tool and with psql, and I get:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "a"
```

It is objecting to the alias. I've tried different names, I've tried inserting the "AS" key word, all to no avail. From what I can tell, Redshift supports table aliases. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Redshift doesn't know about `ctid` because you didn't alias `min(b.ctid)`.

AFAICT, this delete is possible but not in the way you structured it. Your subquery is correlated with the deletion target. I (personally) would not feel confident about the right rows being deleted with that query structure, even it it would run.

Since Redshift does not support joins in `DELETE` I reworked it a bit to use an `IN` list. Innermost to outer it:

- finds the `MIN()` `ctid` per `eventid` for the given date
- joins to `events` again where `ctid` does not match
- concatenates `eventid` with `ctid`
- `DELETE` from events using an `IN` list and the same concat

The advantage here is that you can confirm exactly which combinations of `eventid` and `ctid` will be deleted from the table. It's not clear to me whether you would also need to limit the `events` to a given date in the outer subquery.

```
DELETE FROM events
WHERE eventid||ctid IN (SELECT a.eventid||a.ctid
                        FROM   events AS a  
                        JOIN   (SELECT eventid, MIN(b.ctid) ctid
                                FROM   events
                                WHERE  LEFT(b.eventtimestamp,10)='2016-01-15'
                                GROUP BY eventid) AS b
                        ON     a.eventid = b.eventid
                        AND    a.ctid <> b.ctid
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is that an alias is not supported there- finally tracked down the latest doc and it does not show a table alias as an option for the delete.

Also, /BTW, when I dropped the alias, RS said it didn't know about ctid- which is in Postgres 8.0 and 8.2. So this probably won't work for RS anyway.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem: first alias didn't work, then I found out RedShift doesn't support `ctid`. Did you ever find another field to use instead of it?